# Scanner exception handling

Tags: java

I'm trying to do some simple program and there is a little thing that I curious about at exception handling.

Thus a piece of my code

```
do{
       System.out.println(helloWorld.line);

            System.out.print("Value a : ");
            try{
                if(scan.hasNextInt())
                    rep++;
                a = scan.nextInt();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e){
                rep = 0;
                scan.next();
                System.out.println("Input Mismatch, try again");
            }
            while (rep == 0);
```

and then another code

```
do{
       System.out.println(helloWorld.line);

            System.out.print("Value a : ");
            try{
                if(scan.hasNextInt())
                    rep++;
                a = scan.nextInt();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e){
                rep = 0;
                scan.next();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Input 
                mismatch","Error",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            while(rep == 0);
```

I'm doing a piece of code for ignoring the wrong input and do a loop until the scanner read the correct input also give a popup message.
The question is that the first code works as intended, the second piece is running but doing nothing after the first input and the program not terminated. Why?

Comment: Probably `scan.next();` is blocking

Comment: You could also try just using `Scanner#nextLine()`, which will succeed for any type of input, and then trying to parse that input as integer, or however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-     scan.nextLine(); this line will clear the buffer

```
do{
   System.out.println(helloWorld.line);

        System.out.print("Value a : ");
        try{
             scan.nextLine();
            if(scan.hasNextInt())
                rep++;
            a = scan.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e){
            rep = 0;
            scan.next();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Input 
            mismatch","Error",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        while(rep == 0);
```

For more info: https://itaehun.wordpress.com/2010/09/30/flush-in-java-when-using-nextline/